# How would I get text under an image in Gridlayout in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I am just trying to get a few lines of text under each image here. You can see the code I tried below but obviously it doesn't work.
https://i.gyazo.com/19641174dd3bc136e30f62a1902f5f55.png

```
        rows:2
        cols: 3
        size_hint: 1, .7
        pos_hint: {'center_y':0.55}
        spacing: 100
        padding: 40
        Image:
            source: app.strips
            StackLayout:
                pos: self.pos
                MDLabel:
                    text: "testing"
        Image:
            source: app.cowboyRibeye
        Image:
            source: app.tbone
        Image:
            source: app.boneinStrip
        Image:
            source: app.ribeye
        Image:
            source: app.porterhouse
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom class combining `Image` and `Label` in a layout and use that custom class in place of Image like below:

```
GridLayout:
    rows:2
    cols: 3
    size_hint: 1, .7
    pos_hint: {'center_y':0.55}
    spacing: 100
    padding: 40
    MyImage:
        image_source: app.strips
        subtext: 'strips'
    MyImage:
        image_source: app.cowboyRibeye
        subtext: 'cowboyRibeye'
    MyImage:
        image_source: app.tbone
        subtext: 'tbone'
    MyImage:
        image_source: app.boneinStrip
        subtext: 'boneinStrip'
    MyImage:
        image_source: app.ribeye
        subtext: 'ribeye'
    MyImage:
        image_source: app.porterhouse
        subtext: 'porterhouse'

<MyImage@GridLayout>:
    image_source: ''
    subtext: ''     
    cols: 1
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (1, 1, 1, 1)
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos        
    Image:
        source: root.image_source
        size_hint: 0.9, 0.9
    Label:
        text: root.subtext
        halign: 'center'
        color: 0, 0, 0, 1
        size_hint: 0.1, 0.1
```

**UPDATE:**
`size_hint` property added to `Image` and `Label` in the custom class to properly show the image.

Comment: I will end up using this method. When I did this though all my images became very small. I am needing them to maintain about the same size. What is the purpose of the canvas.before though in this situation? I just don't know it yet and it is probably necessary.

Comment: This can be solved by adding the ```size_hint``` property. The answer is updated to reflect this. Hope this would solve your problem. The purpose of the canvas.before statement is to make the background of the layout of the custom class white to match with app background.